# PHP Accessing class object in parent class

Tags: php, object

This should be easy.. can someone explain the syntax for me?

I have a controller which instantiates a bootstrap class (new keyword) which instantiates the config class.

the controller then instantiates a startpage class which extends the bootstrap class. In the startpage class I'm trying to access the config object in the bootstrap (parent) class.

Can this even be done? Or does startpage have to instantiate bootstrap directly? Does instantiating startpage that extends bootstrap, overwrite bootstrap? or is my syntax just wrong?

Controller (index page)

```
try {
    if (!include($paths['root'] . $paths['framework'] . '/core/AutoLoader.php')) {
        throw new Exception ('<b>Error - AutoLoader is missing</b>');
    }
    $loader   = new AutoLoader($paths);
    $appStack = new BootStrap($paths);
    $app      = new StartPage();
    $app->start();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo
        '<p><b>EXCEPTION</b><br />Message: '
        . $e->getMessage()
        . '<br />File: '
        . $e->getFile()
        . '<br />Line: '
        . $e->getLine()
        . '</p>';
}
```

Bootstrap class:

```
class BootStrap {
    protected $config;

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     ** GETTERS
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     */
    public function getConfig() { return $this->config; }

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * __construct()
     * PUBLIC method
     * = Starts a new session, loads stylesheets, loads classes
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     */
    public function __construct($paths) {

        /**
         * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
         * load Config class
         * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
         *
         */
        try {
            if (!class_exists('Config')) {
                throw new Exception ('<b>Error - Configuration class is missing</b>');
            }
            $this->config      = new Config();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo
                '<p><b>EXCEPTION</b><br />Message: '
                . $e->getMessage()
                . '<br />File: '
                . $e->getFile()
                . '<br />Line: '
                . $e->getLine()
                . '</p>';
        }
    }
}
```

Startpage class:

```
class StartPage extends BootStrap {

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * __construct()
     * PUBLIC method
     * = Starts a new session, loads stylesheets, loads classes
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     */
    public function __construct() {
    }

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Start()
     * PUBLIC method
     * = loads the web page
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     */
    public function Start() {

        // path to includes
        $inc_path = $this->paths['root'] . $this->paths['medium'];

        // instantiate page, html header
        $charset     = $this->config->getCharset();
        $title       = $this->config->getTitle();
        $description = $this->config->getDescription();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing the exception `Configuration class is missing`?

Comment: tried that. **$charset = parent::$config->getCharset();** ... same error.

Comment: @Jamie Nope. Error I get: _Fatal error: Call to a member function getCharset() on a non-object in .._

Comment: Strange thing is.. in the constructor of StartPage I use **$this->paths['uri']** and it doesn't give me an error at all. The problem I think is accessing a class object through a class object in another class object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you give `StartPage` its own `__construct()` method, you effectively "hide" the one in `Bootstrap`, over-riding it completely. So `$foo = new StartPage()` **only** runs the `__construct()` code from the `StartPage` class.

In order to also run the `__construct()` code in the `Bootstrap` parent class, you have to add an explicit call to it, using `parent::__construct()`.

In case you wonder why PHP doesn't do this for you, here are three things you couldn't do if it were automatic:

1. Run code both *before* and *after* the parent constructor, by choosing when to call `parent::__construct()`.
2. Replace the entire constructor logic with something else while still inheriting the rest of the class.
3. Pass values into the parent constructor which are always the same / can be chosen automatically by the child class, but which would need to be provided explicitly to the parent class.

**EDIT:** To summarise the further clarifications below, creating a particular instance of the parent (`Bootstrap`) class will not make any difference to later creations of other instances of the same class or its child class (`StartPage`); each is a separate object and will call `__construct` independently.

If you want multiple `StartPage` objects to refer to one particular instance of the `Bootstrap` class, then inheritance is not the right mechanism. Instead, you will need to pass the created `Bootstrap` instance into each `StartPage` instance via some form of Dependency Injection.

Comment: But I am already calling Bootstrap from the controller. I have edited the original post to show this.

Comment: So, the constructor for the bootstrap can be called twice from two different places? I'm confused by this..

Comment: @obmon I think you are confusing Classes and Objects. When you create a new `StartPage` object, it doesn't know anything about any other objects which have been created, of class `Bootstrap` or `StartPage`. What you need to do is initialise the data in that specific `StartPage` object, and only `StartPage::__construct()` can do that.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm still in the OOP learning curve... but StartPage extends Bootstrap.. so it should already "know" about the BootStrap object that should already be instantiated...

Comment: Oh! I see.. So the first time I instantiate BootStrap it is not the same as the Extended Bootstrap when I instantiate StartPage.. right?

Comment: @obmon Consider a more "concrete" example: a class called `Vehicle` and a class called `Car` which extends it. Whenever I run `$foo = new Vehicle()`, the `__construct()` method on `Vehicle` is called to create **that specific vehicle**. I can create as many Vehicles as I like; they do not know about each other. If I run `$foo = new Car()` instead, it is not tied to one of the existing `Vehicle`s, it is its own object, so it needs to do its own setup. If it has its own `__construct()` method, that is what will be run.

Comment: Ok, I get it, It's not loading the bootstrap constructor which loads a config object, as it is a new bootstrap object.. But then, that would mean that I am loading the Config class twice.. maybe its better to change how this is designed..?

Comment: @obmon Yes, if you run `$myBootstrapObject = new Bootstrap(); $myStartPageObject = new StartPage();`, you are creating two unrelated objects. But since `$myStartPageObject` is actually an extended `Bootstrap`, you don't need `$myBootstrapObject` at all, so just don't run that first line.

Comment: So the best way to inherit a class already instantiated, is not to extend, but to pass on the object through dependency injection..

Comment: Or like you said.. I can instantiate StartPage without instantiating bootstrap first.. the thing is, I was intending for the design to be able to have 1 bootstrap, but multiple startpages (modules) using the same bootstrap.. won't be able to do that now without using DI..

Comment: @obmon Yes, if you want multiple objects to refer to a particular _instance_ of the `Bootstrap` class, then inheritance is not the right mechanism.

Comment: Thanks IMSoP. Dependency Injection it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the constructor of the Child Class and explicitly call the constructor of the parent.

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't that overwrite the previous instantiation of the class from the controller? Seems kinda hackish too..

Comment: Not really, the object of a class is instantiated only once anyway. You are just making sure any constructors are called in the super class as well when the child class is called.

Answer (score 0):

In StartPage:

```
protected $config;

public function __construct() 
{
   $this->config = $this->getConfig();
}
```

Or, following xelber's answer, use `parent::__construct();`

Comment: We want to inherit the existing instantiation, not copy-and-paste it.

Comment: The above variable declaration will work. Not sure who this mythical 'we' is.